# nestjs mock imported module

Tags: testing, jestjs, nestjs

I'm trying to test my `AuthModule` controller **HTTP layer** with `supertest` as described in the official [Nestjs documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#end-to-end-testing). This module uses an `EmailService` imported from an `EmailModule`.

I know you can override providers as follows:

```js
const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        AuthModule,
      ],
    })
      .overrideProvider(EmailService)
      .useValue(buildMock(EmailService))
```

but this doesn't work, I'm assuming because the `EmailModule` is imported in the `AuthModule`. A workaround is to `.overrideProvider(...).useValue(...)` every provider in the `EmailModule`, but this non sense as I'd then have to also mock modules imported by the `EmailModule`.

When I'm e2e testing the `AuthModule`, I honestly don't care about how the `EmailModule` works. All I should need to mock is the `EmailService` and make sure my auth module interacts with that service properly.

The `Test.createTestingModule({})` doesn't have a `.overrideModule()` method, unfortunately.

I tried mocking the `EmailModule` with jest:

```js
jest.mock('../../src/email/email.module.ts', () => {
  @Module({})
  class EmailModule {

  }

  return EmailModule;
});
```

but I get this error:

```
Error: Nest cannot create the module instance. Often, this is because of a circular dependency between modules. Use forwardRef() to avoid it.

(Read more: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency)
Scope [RootTestModule -> AppModule]
```

Does anyone know how this can be achieved ?

Comment: "I'm assuming because the EmailModule is imported in the AuthModule"

No, `overrideProvider` allows overriding any provider in the context. Thus, if `EmailService` exists in your app context, it will be overriden.

Could you show the `@Module()` part of the `AuthModule` and the `EmailModule`?

Comment: Yes, overriding the EmailService isn't the problem. The problem I have is that I want to mock the entire Email module without having to mock everything thats imported and every provider of that module. My EmailModule exports an EmailService and uses an EmailRepository, so I'd have to mock both in this case. What I want is to tell the AuthModule to use a fake EmailModule, and I can provide the EmailService manually.

Comment: Hi! Did you solve this issue? I'm facing the same problem here and I didn't find a solution yet.

Comment: Nope, to this day I haven't found a solution, sorry :(

Comment: I need a solution too, testing in nestjs is a pain because of this

Comment: @user5365075 did my solution helped? Let me know if you need anymore info or I missed the target

Comment: the solution is provided by @nicola below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70420769/2755480

Answer (score 6):

I spent quite a long time to try figure how to mock a full NestJS module. Below is what works for me.

```js
// Create a valid NestJS module to be used in place of the one we want to mock
@Module({})
class MockModule {}

// Identify the Module you want to mock and mock it
jest.mock('module-to-mock', () => {
  return {
    ModuleToMockName: {
      forRootAsync: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => MockModule),
    }
  };
});
```

Basically we provide NestJS with a valid module that in this case does nothing but could be coded to behave in a predictable / testable way.

Comment: this answer is golden!

Comment: I still get an error `The module at index [5] is of type "undefined"` and that is exactly the index of the module I am trying to mock

Answer (score 3):

The way I solved this is by creating a `TestModule` that is global:

```js
    @Global()
    @Module({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: EmailService,
          useValue: {} // mock
        },
      ],
    })
    class TestModule {}
```

Import the `TestModule` at the beginning of your testing module:

```js
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        TestModule,
        AuthModule,
        // ...
      ]
    }).compile();
```

That way, the `EmailService` is provided globally and you don't need to import the `EmailModule` anymore.

Global modules are explained [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#global-modules).

Answer (score 1):

NestJS has its own way to do the trick: [official docs here](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#auto-mocking)

With this piece of code you can auto-mock everything that is not defined:

```js
...
import { ModuleMocker, MockFunctionMetadata } from 'jest-mock';

const moduleMocker = new ModuleMocker(global);

...

beforeAll(async () => {
    moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AuthModule, LoginModule, ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }), CacheModule, SessionDataModule],
      controllers: [SessionController],
      providers: [ConfigService, SessionService, UserService],
    })
    // This is the important part
    .useMocker((token) => {
      // Inject a mock for every dependency not declared (this avoids lots of unnecessary "imports")
      if (typeof token === 'function') {
        const mockMetadata = moduleMocker.getMetadata(token) as MockFunctionMetadata<any, any>;
        const Mock = moduleMocker.generateFromMetadata(mockMetadata);
        return new Mock();
      }
    })
    .compile();
  });
```

That `useMocker(...)` injects a Mock for everything that is not imported/defined. Using the token parameter you are able to mock specific items, for example you can check `token.name === 'MyService'` and inject a specific mock.

This code

```js
if (typeof token === 'function') {
    const mockMetadata = moduleMocker.getMetadata(token) as MockFunctionMetadata<any, any>;
    const Mock = moduleMocker.generateFromMetadata(mockMetadata);
    return new Mock();
}
```

Basically takes the definition of the module that is missing and create a Mock on-the-fly for that module.

Hope you find that useful!

Answer (score 0):

did you try just to provide the EmailService in the testing module? It would look something like this:

```
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [
    EmailService        
  ],
}).compile();
```

I think you can just skip importing the entire EmailModule and just provide what is needed