# NestJS - Reflect.getMetadata TypeError while running e2e tests

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, jestjs, nestjs

The error:

```
[Nest] 163363  - 10/03/2022, 11:59:37 AM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 163363  - 10/03/2022, 11:59:37 AM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] 
TypeError
    at Reflect.getMetadata (/home/mszan/foo/source/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js:354:23)
    at DependenciesScanner.isInjectable (/home/mszan/foo/source/node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:302:26)
    at DependenciesScanner.insertModule (/home/mszan/foo/source/node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:73:18)
    at DependenciesScanner.scanForModules (/home/mszan/foo/source/node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:34:43)
    at DependenciesScanner.scan (/home/mszan/foo/source/node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:27:20)
    at async /home/mszan/foo/source/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-factory.js:95:17
    at async Function.asyncRun (/home/mszan/foo/source/node_modules/@nestjs/core/errors/exceptions-zone.js:22:13)
    at async NestFactoryStatic.initialize (/home/mszan/foo/source/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-factory.js:94:13)
    at async NestFactoryStatic.create (/home/mszan/foo/source/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-factory.js:37:9)
  ●  process.exit called with "1"

      at DEFAULT_TEARDOWN (../../node_modules/@nestjs/core/errors/exceptions-zone.js:6:40)
      at Function.asyncRun (../../node_modules/@nestjs/core/errors/exceptions-zone.js:29:13)
      at async NestFactoryStatic.initialize (../../node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-factory.js:94:13)
      at async NestFactoryStatic.create (../../node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-factory.js:37:9)
```

The `app.e2e-spec.ts`:

```js
describe('app - e2e', () => {
    let app: INestApplication;

    beforeAll(async () => {
        const moduleRef: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            ...appModuleMetadata,
            imports: appModuleMetadata.imports.map((x) => {
                if (x == CommonModule) {
                    return CommonModuleMock;
                }
                return x;
            }),
        }).compile();
        app = moduleRef.createNestApplication();
        await app.init();
    });
});
```

The `CommonModule` contains a provider that imports `fs` and `path` packages. When I remove these imports, the tests work.
As you can see, I tried replacing `CommonModule` with `CommonModuleMock` that does not contain mentioned imports but the tests still fail.

Nest version is 9.0.11. Jest is 29.0.3. Supertest is 6.2.4. Node is 16.17.0.

What are my options?

Comment: the way you are mocking the import seems weird.. I imagine there's a jest way of doing it using `jest.mock` at the top of your test script

Comment: @RobertRendell It is, I agree. I wanted to be explicit about module metadata object. In other words, my goal was to point out that the metadata object does not contain ``CommonModule`` at all but still fails due to ``fs`` and ``path`` imports. However, I also tried using ``jest.mock`` same way as it was used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70420769/13273250). Same error.

Comment: I got the same error when I added `ScheduleModule.forRoot()` into `app.module.ts` as documented. testcontainers said `TypeError` with no helpful information how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I will try this.

I had the same problem , then i went back and verified all dependencies.

i had some constants defined in the main.js referenced by a controller.

May be check your main.js exports this helped me to solve that exact same  (error message) you have.